# NSImage lockFocus and NSString size on retina display

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-text

I'm facing a weird issue, I'm drawing inside an NSImage using the following pseudo-code:

```
NSString* text = @"Hello world!";
NSDictionary *dict = [[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSColor colorWithCGColor:textColor],NSForegroundColorAttributeName,font, NSFontAttributeName,nil] autorelease];

NSMutableAttributedString* str = [[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text attributes:dict] autorelease];

NSSize stringSize = [str size];
NSImage* image = [[[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:stringSize] autorelease];
[image lockFocus];
NSRect drawRect = NSMakeRect(0,0,stringSize.width,stringSize.height);
[str drawInRect:drawRect];
[image unlockFocus];
```

Now the problem is that, with a dual monitor configuration, if I keep my retina display open, the string is mangled (I get half of the string drawn), while by simply closing my retina display and using only my cinema display, the string is drawn correctly. It's like the NSImage is getting the default context and some scaling factor from the retina display.

Do you have any hints ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I will keep this for future reference, even there's something about displaying NSImage that covers the same aspect.

No matter what's your primary display but seems that the NSGraphicContext comes with an affine transformation that multiplies x 2 to address the retina resolution.

You just need to reset the affine transformations, before drawing into NSImage with:

```
NSAffineTransform *trans = [[[NSAffineTransform alloc] init] autorelease];
[trans set];
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on this as I tried to duplicate this and could not use it to fix the problem.  Thanks.

Comment: what is your problem exactly ?

Comment: Event with the transform set before/during the drawing, the result is still a retina sized image (ie 4 times the pixels), but maybe this isn't intended to solve that issue.

Comment: could you post some code ? Are you talking about events coordinates ? (or you intended to write even ...)

Comment: My objective was to create an NSImage with initWithSize that was that size in pixels.  This solution does not do that (which is fine if it solves the OPs problem).  The only solution I've found is to create CGBitmapContextCreate, CGBitmapContextCreateImage, and imageWithCGImage.